# How can I implement fuzzy search using solr

Tags: solr, fuzzy

For example, I have got a name with first name, middle name and last name. I need to search different combinations of name like {first name, middle name, last name},{middle name, first name, last name} and so on(6 combinations). In the mean time, names must be search with phonetic also. Like for the name "John", it must pick "Jonn". Also for "Mohammed" it must make a hit "Mohammad" or "Mouhammed" This phonetic search is applicable for all the three parts of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use fieldType `phonetic_en` for name**

Field Type `phonetic_en` included in the default schema, If not use the below schema :

```
<fieldType name="phonetic_en" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Example :

```
<field name="cfname" type="phonetic_en" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

[DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-DoubleMetaphoneFilter) :

> This filter creates tokens using the   DoubleMetaphone  encoding algorithm from commons-codec.  For more information, see the [Phonetic Matching](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Phonetic+Matching) section.

Comment: The db contains various names like "Bell Aleksander Greham", "Graham Alexander Bell" etc. If I give a name "Alexander Graham Bell" as a query, and then will it return all those names ?

Comment: yes. it will return all of those name ignoring order

Comment: I have added the above code to schema.xml. But it shows error when I search for a string which contain spaces in between first name and middle name.

Comment: {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "name:MOHAMMED MUTLAQ ABU JHESHEH",
      "indent": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1499665071823"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "undefined field text",
    "code": 400
  }
}

Comment: Did you reload the core/collection and reindex after schema changed ?

Comment: I have reloaded the core as well as re indexed the data.

Comment: The error says  "undefined field text", means there is no field text. Did you use the field "text" ?

Comment: <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
This is the code I have written in schema.xml with respect to the database.
Is there any error in giving the type as "string"

Comment: You define the type of the name as string, you should define the type as `phonetic_en`

Comment: <field name="name" type="phonetic_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
I have edited it as above. But the error is still there. Reloaded index and core.

Comment: Show your full query

Comment: <dataConfig>
 <dataSource name="ds-1" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.95.200:1020/test" user="abc" password="abc"/>
 <document>
 <entity name="item" dataSource="ds-1" query="select NAME from RECS">
 <field column="NAME" name="name" />
 </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
This is dbdataconfig.xml
The below code and your code is included in schema.xml
<field name="name" type="phonetic_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: One more issue. If the search name is given as "John David Miller", then it fetches results which contains that John or David or Miller also. I need those rows which contains all the three parts of the name which can be in different combinations. Can u help with that ?

Comment: use query like this `name:(+John +David +Miller)`. It will return document which contain all the three word. Here `+` means that the following term must be present.

Comment: What if the search query be, if I want John to come as first part of the result and Miller as the last part ? It is not a concern that anything can come in between John and Miller.  eg :-- John abc egfg Miller . 
What all tricks are there in solr search query that can be performed to get different results ?

Comment: @AkhilValayil then you should use [Phrase Query](http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/) Ex. `name:"John Miller"~2` will match "John abc egfg Miller". Here ~2 means edit distance 2

Comment: What all operations are left in solr search query? I want to perform every possible search